# SQL Server CE: Update statement using DateTime in Where clause

Tags: c#, datetime, sql-server-ce, sql-update

I need to be able to update time information for a row in the table. The id is not unique so I also use the `startTime` column to find the specific row. I am using SQL Server CE and C# so the date objects are a `DateTime` object in C#.

Is there another way to optimise this? I can't seem to be getting a match with the `WHERE` clause and the `startTime`? `startTime` is a `datetime` datatype in SQL Server CE.

```
UPDATE tablename
SET endTime = '14/04/2012 9:42:58 PM', duration = '0.052003'
WHERE (startTime = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-04-14 21:42:58.000', 120)) AND (id= '14363204')
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Start with just a simple SELECT statement rather than an UPDATE. Get that working first.
2. Use datetime literals.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE startTime = '2012-04-14 21:42:58.000' AND id = '14363204'
```

If this doesn't work, the most likely problem is that the time isn't an exact match. Possible reason for this can include:

- The datetime in your database may be stored with millisecond precision but your query is using a value that appears to have been rounded off to the nearest second. This can cause the match to fail.
- The dates in the database may have been stored in a different time zone.

Comment: The time definitely doesnt match up. In the database its recorded as '14/04/2012 8:51:00 PM'. When I try to match the same or even '2012-04-14 20:51:00.000' doesnt show any results on the select statement. Do I need to do something special for precision on the database?

Comment: @Ourx: The time might be stored with millisecond precision, but the milliseconds might not be displayed. Using a timestamp as (or as paart of) an ID is generally a bad idea unless you can be sure that you use the same timezone and precision consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Why `CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-04-14 21:42:58.000', 120)`? Do you pass your startTime as a string? This may be a problem. startTime.ToString() (in C#) maybe produce another format than you expected? Do you use dynamic SQL (mean: you build query in C# as a string and then fire it)?

Decompose your query and check passed params.

```
DECLARE @startTime DATETIME = '2012-04-14 21:42:58.000'
DECLARE @endTime DATETIME = '14/04/2012 9:42:58 PM'
DECLARE @duration DECIMAL = 0.052003
DECLARE @id INT = 14363204

-- debug - check if your input parameters are as expected
SELECT @startTime AS startTime, @endTime AS endTime, @duration AS duration

-- do the update
UPDATE  tablename
SET  endTime = @endTime, duration = @duration
WHERE  startTime = @startTime AND id = @id
```

I suggest you to wrap above into `CREATE PROCEDURE` and execute stored procedure from C# and not use dynamic SQL.

I do not know if it's possible in SQL CE but in full edition you have SQL Profiler that makes you able to catch and examine queries sent to SQL Server by your app.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting your time using the 120 date style, which strips off milliseconds. If the startTime value was generated using GETDATE() for instance, it won't match.

I'd recommend to stick to the ISO-8601 date format whenever you're dealing with dates in SQL (style 121) because it removes the need for CONVERT() calls, and more importantly it is not regional settings-dependent (your code would fail on a french or german SQL Server for instance).

```
UPDATE tablename
SET endTime = '20120414 21:42:58', duration = '0.052003'
WHERE startTime = '20120414 21:42:58.000' AND id = '14363204'
```

Try a `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, startTime, 121) FROM tablename WHERE id = '14363204'` to see if there's any millisecond for the startTime you want to update.